# Story about demons in the ethernet

Tags: story-identification

This was a story about a skilled thief (and I think he was also a dog...but a humanoid dog) out to steal some quality jewelery from some castle residents.  He decided to trick them with a modem; although he insisted to them that it was a working modem, he knew it was broken, and it could be safely plugged into the castle's ancient ethernet without fear of releasing a demon.

> But a castle assistant, some kind of savant, realized the modem was broken, and suddenly fixed it after it was plugged in, ruining the plan and releasing a real demon.  The jewels the thief turned out to steal were fake anyway.

Google hasn't helped me find this one so far...I'm hoping someone else might recognize it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's ["The Dog Said Bow-Wow"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/189239152X) by Michael Swanwick.

The dog was called *Sir Blackthorpe Ravenscairn de Plus Precieux*, or Surplus for short, and his assistant was *Darger*.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! With the title and author I was able to not only verify that you were correct, but find a complete version of the story online (I assume legally, since it's on Asimov's). http://www.asimovs.com/_issue_0206/bowwow.shtml

Comment: There is a sequel, too. Set in Italy. Nymphs and satyrs are involved. The name is escaping me, just now.

Comment: All of the Darger & Surplus stories are collected in *The Dog Said Bow-Wow*. There's a novel, *Dancing with Bears*, which will come out in paperback next month.

Comment: The castle's ancient ethernet... and it was identified!